# AWS static site with S3 and CoudFront, downloading index.html file instead of serving it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

My website was not showing the changes I made to it. Thinking it was a caching issue, I edited the Cache-Control metadata of the index file to "max-age=0" in S3 and created a "/index.html" invalidation in cloudfront. Neither worked and now when I visit the website: https://imaginext.app it downloads the index file instead of serving it.

Note that:

- the site worked before my attempts to fix it,
- the url given by S3 [S3 Link](http://imaginext.app.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com) serves the site perfectly,
- and the Content-Type metadata for the index file is "text/html"

If there is any more info you need to solve the problem let me know and I will provide it.

Comment: Your site loads normally in a test environment for me.  I'd try clearing your local cache and/or trying a browser that's never visited it before.

Comment: @AnonCoward looks like clearing the local cache worked. Off the top of your head, is there a way to have this done automatically when I post new changes? Or is this something I should just get used to doing.

Comment: Not that I know of.  I'm personally in the habit of using a guest session or inprivate/incognito window where a local cache might be problematic.

Comment: Did you remove the `Content-Type` metadata while investigating the issue?

Comment: you might have cached an old version before you disabled cache.  you typically have to clear local cache only between cache timeout and content change.